# Java while loop variable accessing from outside

Tags: java, variables

How to access variable that is in the while loop from outside it ?

Answer (score 5):

Always declare variables at the scope that makes sense. If your variable is to be referenced both inside and outside a loop, then it must be declared outside the loop.

```
public String doIt() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        builder.append("ponies ");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

It is good practice to narrow the scope of variables so that they are only visible where they are needed.

Answer (score 3):

a) don't. it's a bad idea

b)
Define it outside the loop

```
int x;
while(something){
    x = somethingElse;
}
```

Comment: Re (a): Recommend removing that part of your answer. This can be a perfectly reasonable thing to do. Like almost everything else in programming, it can be abused, but is not necessarily wrong.

Comment: Agree. In an imperative language this is how loop constructs are used to build state.

Comment: Ok my answer sounded too harsh. I agree it's sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable outside the loop.